# PATH variable when calling make from XCode

Tags: xcode, makefile, environment-variables

For an iPad application I need to transform some CoffeeScript files into JavaScript files before bundling them with the application.

I tried to add a Makefile to my XCode project with the following code:

```
MANUAL_ROOT=IOS12BSH/manual
SCRIPTS_ROOT=$(MANUAL_ROOT)/scripts

COFFEE_SOURCES=$(SCRIPTS_ROOT)/*.coffee $(SCRIPTS_ROOT)/guides/*.coffee
JAVASCRIPT_TARGETS=$(COFFEE_SOURCES:.coffee=.js)

all: build

build: coffeescript

clean: clean_coffeescript

coffeescript: $(JAVASCRIPT_TARGETS)

clean_coffeescript:
    rm -f $(JAVASCRIPT_TARGETS)

$(JAVASCRIPT_TARGETS): $(COFFEE_SOURCES)
    coffee -c $(COFFEE_SOURCES)
```

Running this Makefile from the shell works without problems. However, after I added the Makefile as a target in XCode, I ran into problems.

The following error was produced by the Makefile:

```
coffee -c IOS12BSH/manual/scripts/*.coffee IOS12BSH/manual/scripts/guides/*.coffee
/bin/sh: coffee: command not found
make: *** [IOS12BSH/manual/scripts/*.js] Error 127
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make failed with exit code 2
```

That is strange, as the `coffee` command is installed on my machine (it is installed under `/opt/local/bin/coffee` and `/opt/local/bin` is added to my `$PATH` in `~/.profile`).

So I added an `echo $(PATH)` to my Makefile and it seems that the `$PATH` is different, when the Makefile is executed by XCode. XCode does not seem to read the settings from `~/.profile` and therefore `/opt/local/bin` is not in `$PATH`.

What is the reason for this and how can I fix this, so that the `coffee` command is found?

Comment: Why not modify your "`$PATH`" within your makefile to add "`/opt/local/bin`"? How are you running your makefile within Xcode?  Is it in a "run script" build phase?

Comment: I can't change it in the Makefile because the Makefile is in a shared repository. Other developers might have installed their `coffee` command somewhere else.

Comment: I've got no experience with `Makefile`'s but can you not `source ~/.profile` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems that programs started via the Dock or Spotlight do not execute `.profile` and therefore `$PATH` is not set correctly.

So one way would be to set the `$PATH` in `~/.MacOSX/environments.plist`. That works then apparently, but you will need a restart before it works.

Another way is to start XCode always from the command line with `open projectfile`.

Comment: that should be `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` not plural `environments.plist`. :)

Comment: Is there any clever way here to set this path to be sourced from the ~/.profile?

Comment: Hmm, I just checked and I actually already have `/opt/local/bin` in that plist file.. (OS 10.8; XCode 4.6.3). But it still doesn't seem to be able to find the file. After actually printing out the path in the Makefile like the OP suggested, I found that this path is actually very different from the path in `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` and it doesn't include `/opt/local/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer explains the problem in detail:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14285335/751061

What ended up working best for me is just to launch Xcode from the command line.
I wrote a simple bash script that looks like:

```
source ~/.bash_profile  # This is the trick that gets us our environment variables.
open -a "Xcode"
```

And then I call it from an Applescript Application just to give it a bundle I could put on the dock:

```
do shell script "~/xcode_launcher"
```

Sourcing your profile is necessary in the bash script, because running a script from Applescript doesn't ever source from a profile, so you still wouldn't have your default environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

SAme thing with `ant` command. It works on terminal, not if Xcode have to do it. Only way to got it work: `sudo open project.xcodeproj` in terminal.