# How to set environment variables to an application on OSX Mountain Lion?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, environment-variables, osx-mountain-lion

since the upgrade to OSX Mountain Lion I‘ve got some problems with setting the environment variables for eclipse and maven.

My goal is to run a maven command in Eclipse. This command needs to download artefacts (resolve dependencies) from a remote repository. The repository is authenticated via HTTPS.

I‘ve followed the [Guide to Remote repository access through authenticated HTTPS](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html) and added the lines below to my .bash_profil . If I‘m running maven in the terminal everythings works fine.

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Users/myUser/.knowncerts/trust.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=trustPwd"
```

But this does only work for the terminal and not for applications. On previous OSX-Versions you had to add the MAVEN_OPTS variable to

```
~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
```

(see also [Set environment variables on Mac OS X Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion)) This worked for OSX Lion perfectly.

But Apple has changed this behaviour on Mountain Lion. I‘ve read the environment.plist is no longer supported and the new way is to edit the Info.plist of the .app itself ([Where are system environment variables set in Mountain Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57385/where-are-system-environment-variables-set-in-mountain-lion)). It seems you have to add a [LSEnvironment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html) dictionary containing all you variables.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LSEnvironment</key>
    <dict>
        <key>M2_HOME</key>
        <string>/usr/share/maven</string>
        <key>MAVEN_OPTS</key>
        <string>-Xmx512m -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Users/myUser/.knowncerts/trust.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=trustPwd</string>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>eclipse</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>Eclipse 3.8 for Mac OS X, Copyright IBM Corp. and others 2002, 2011. All rights reserved.</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>Eclipse.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>org.eclipse.eclipse</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Eclipse</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>3.8</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>3.8</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
        <string>ar</string>
        <string>cs</string>
        <string>da</string>
        <string>el</string>
        <string>en</string>
        <string>es</string>
        <string>de</string>
        <string>fi</string>
        <string>fr</string>
        <string>hu</string>
        <string>it</string>
        <string>iw</string>
        <string>ja</string>
        <string>ko</string>
        <string>nl</string>
        <string>no</string>
        <string>pl</string>
        <string>pt_BR</string>
        <string>pt</string>
        <string>ru</string>
        <string>sv</string>
        <string>tr</string>
        <string>zh_HK</string>
        <string>zh_TW</string>
        <string>zh</string>
    </array>
    <key>Eclipse</key>
    <array>
        <string>-keyring</string>
        <string>~/.eclipse_keyring</string>
        <string>-showlocation</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

As you can see I changed the Info.plist of my Eclipse.app. But this did not work. I start maven within Eclipse. But maven is not able to download the artefacts, because the remote repository is not trusted. I think Eclipse does not use the environment variables I defined in the Info.plist

Do you have any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 32):

Unfortunately, this seems to be the best option for setting a global environment variable in OS X 10.8.x Mountain Lion:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/588442/705157

For temporary environment variables, run this command in Terminal.app, and restart any apps that need to access the variable:

```
launchctl setenv MYVARIABLE value
```

To make an environment variable persistent across reboots, create `/etc/launchd.conf` and add a line like this for each variable, then reboot your entire system:

```
setenv MYVARIABLE value
```

This worked for me to set a global environment variable that could be inherited by IntelliJ IDEA CE 12.0 on OS X 10.8.2. Not very elegant, but it works.

Alternatively, you can set the environment variable in Terminal.app, then launch the App from which you want to access the environment variable from the command-line. The launched app will inherit the environment from your terminal session. In Terminal.app, set the environment variable and launch another app with a command like `open -a "App Name"`:

```
export MYVARIABLE=value
open -a "IntelliJ IDEA 12 CE"
```

This opens IntelliJ IDEA, and my code can access `$MYVARIABLE` in its environment.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore for later `macOS` versions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26586170/9636

Comment: @HeathBorders It worked for me on Macbook Pro 2023

Answer (score 1):

From here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10374886/325742

```
#!/bin/sh
#
export MAVEN_OPTS=#MAVEN_OPTS_HERE#
LAUNCHER_JAR=/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar

java \
-showversion \
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m \
-Xms1024m \
-Xmx1024m \
-Xdock:icon=/Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/Resources/Eclipse.icns \
-XstartOnFirstThread \
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts \
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 \
-jar $LAUNCHER_JAR
```

Then, use the steps on http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shell-script-mac-apps, to turn the above script into an application that can be kept on the dock.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve my problem. When I start Eclipse with the script, it still does not use the 'MAVEN_OPTS'. But if I export for example a different 'M2_HOME', Eclipse uses this new Maven-Home.

Answer (score 0):

You can set env variable directly in eclipse under maven "Debug Configurations" -> "Environment" tab

Answer (score -1):

Steps of commands on terminal window:

1. vi ~/.bash_profile
2. Press i (to bring the vi editor in edit mode)
3. Enter the environment variable in the vi editor window

   - e.g. export JAVA_HOME=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/java8
4. esc key followed by :wq
5. source ~/.bash_profile