# ImportError: No module named mechanize - XCode 6.1 is not seeing newly installed python libraries

Tags: python, xcode6, mechanize, python-requests, osx-yosemite

Recently I installed Mac OS Yosemite. Until then I had no problem in installing libraries and have already installed beautiful soup, pydelicious, etc. After the installation of Yosemite, I tried to install Mechanize and Requests Libraries in mac. There was no problem in their installation. I could import them and use them from the Terminal. However, Xcode 6.1 doesn't load them/seeing them. I consistently get the

> ImportError: No module named mechanize
>
> ImportError: No module named requests
> error messages.

I have already tried changing the file permissions with full access to the user but to no avail.
I also checked PYTHONPATH and .profile files, so far no luck.

I wonder, if any has encountered this problem or if any one know of some fix to this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by Xcode not seeing them?  Why would it use them anyway given its only python-enabled element is `lldb`?

Comment: I've given the error messages. When I use import in my XCode, the module fails to load. Please see the error message given. This apparently is happening only after I switched to Yosemite.

Comment: To be clear; you are using xcode to develop in Python?

Comment: Yes...The instructions are available in the internet.

Comment: Well there are couple of things potentially wrong; firstly Xcode might be using the system version of python and any user-added modules might be for a different version (i.e. macports/homebrew) and secondly your particular issue seems to relate to getting an OSX app to pick-up environment variable changes.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165385/how-to-set-environment-variables-to-an-application-on-osx-mountain-lion) for how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Xcode was referring to my default of Python. 
After the comment from Droppy, I checked my python version by using

> which python

I copy pasted the result in the Xcode Program scheme. Now it works...!

Thanks for all the help.