# OSX Android studio's gradle cannot read .bash_profile environment variable

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, osx-yosemite

I am having a KEY_STRING as system variable in mac OSX and Windows. Which has absolute path to my keystore.

~/.bash_profile entry would be

```
export KEY_STRING =~/config/release-signing.keystore
```

Same path setup in each of my team mates machines[Windows/OSX/Linux].

My Gradle script to access this variable would be

```
def keystorePath = System.getenv("KEY_STRING");
println keystorePath;
```

This script works fine in Windows in both console and android studio.

My problem specific to **mac android studio**.

If I run the build in terminal which is working fine and reads the env variable.

But when I do gradle sync or set up run configuration [Gradle task] it cannot resolve the variable.

I have reported this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=184672) to Google as well.

Again here is the quick summary:

- Setup an environment variable in ~/.bash_profile
- Read it anywhere in build.gradle

  def keystorePath = System.getenv("KEY_STRING");
  println keystorePath;
- Add gradle task in configuration.
  [image: Adding custom gradle task to android studio]
- It is not reading the environment variable.

Comment: Not at all.. It is specific to android studio's gradle. It cannot read the variable.

Comment: ... because OSX app's don't have access to environment variables set in `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Is there any workaround to put these env variable?

I didn't want to mess my build.gradle

Comment: Did you read the answer I linked?

Comment: Yes.. I read it's no longer working in Yosmite with 30 upvotes in comment.

Comment: OK, but you are on the right track.  Find the process/file necessary to set in the system config that will allow you to set environment variables within OSX apps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88716/discussion-between-mahe-madhi-and-trojanfoe).

Answer (score 6):

**None** of the OSX apps can read the environment variable.

As per this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14285335/981555

solution for my problem would be

```
launchctl setenv KEY_STRING ~/config/release-signing.keystore
```

This should be set before launching Android studio.

Comment: To add to this answer, I was actually able to get the environment variables set automatically on OSX Login by using a combination of AppleScript saved as Application, Started on Login Items in Users and Groups, and using this syntax: `do shell script "launchctl setenv ANDROID_HOME /users/$(whoami)/Library/Android/sdk"`. This runs the launchctl setenv when the user logs in and then applications and terminal can see the environment variables