# failed to build Gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to build a repo from `GitHub` using `Android Studio` and whenever I try to build it, this message appears:

```
-Unable to find Gradle tasks to build: [:]. Build mode: REBUILD. Tests: None.
-Multiple Gradle daemons might be spawned because the Gradle JDK and JAVA_HOME locations are different. Project
```

I tried different versions of `Android SDK` and `Java JDK`.
I tried to put `Java JDK` and the project file in the same path, but none of them worked.

Any help in this matter is appreciated.

Comment: whats the repo?

Comment: a Github repository

Comment: yes, i got that. If you'd like some help, I could try to clone the repo and try to work out the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/hamza372/hamza372-ImageClassificationJavaStarter/tree/main

Comment: I've cloned the repo. Android studio flagged that the sdk location was invalid and I allowed the known location for my sdk install. Gradle then sync'd and the project built.

Comment: thank you, I did so, but now I have this error: Failed to notify dependency resolution listener

Comment: and this error when I click on run button The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem,Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes

Comment: I'd do what it says

Comment: @user21408341, You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56192983/android-studio-is-using-this-jdk-location-which-is-different-to-what-gradle)