# How do I launch a mac (osx/macos) app with an environment variable set?

Tags: macos, environment-variables

How do I launch a mac app with an environment variable set?

Everything I can find is really complicated, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165385/how-to-set-environment-variables-to-an-application-on-osx-mountain-lion), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-on-os-x) or [this](https://superuser.com/questions/476752/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x-for-gui-applications).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting environment variables on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-on-os-x)

Answer (score 2):

It's actually really simple.

Open up `Terminal` and run:

```
~$ export MY_VAR=some-value
~$ open /Applications/Some.app
```

Comment: Or just `MY_VAR=some-value open /Applications/Some.app`

Comment: how do you do this for login items?